# Editing finished mysql table

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

I'm new to mysql and I want to edit my table. My primary key should be auto generated.

[image: http://img5.fotos-hochladen.net/uploads/20140221195edaphnx1q0.png]

So where can I get the option to edit my table? thanks

Comment: Can you rephrase this  it doesn't make much sense. Ar eoyu looking for info on how to edit it in general, or specifically how to add a PK?  Have you got MySQL Workbench or alike yet?

Comment: Sorry. I already have created a table "vokabeln" - now I want to edit my primary key -> to autogenerated.  Yes MySQL Workbench.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL Workbench:

- Right-click on the table you want to alter.
- Select **Alter Table...**
- Place a check-mark under "**PK**" for the field(s) you want to assign as a Primary Key.
- Hit **Apply**.

[image]

Comment: @user3338614 No problem. :)